# Implement function in click event

Tags: c#

So i have created a function ParseandWarn to pop up a message box if the input is not an integer. If it is an integer, the sum of both inputs must be calculated on the click event. There are multiple calculations, that is why i created the function. **How do I implement/activate this function in the click event?** I am getting an error, probably the parsing?
I am new to programming, any help is welcome.

```
  public void ParseandWarn()
    {
        int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtGetal1.Text, out Invoergetal1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("U dient een geheel getal in te voeren!", "Fout", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(txtGetal2.Text, out Invoergetal2))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("U dient een geheel getal in te voeren!", "Fout", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int BerekenSom = int.Parse(txtGetal1.Text) + int.Parse(txtGetal2.Text);
        txtResultaat.Text += "De som van " + txtGetal1.Text + " en " + txtGetal2.Text + " = " + BerekenSom + Environment.NewLine;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the function inside the event handler?

Comment: Well I don't know how to do that in a 'proper' way ...

Comment: ParseAndWarn();

Comment: I did that, but i get a FormatException afterwards ...

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the FormatException?

Comment: I get the error on the line 'int BerekenSom = int.Parse(txtGetal1.Text) + int.Parse(txtGetal2.Text);' and I have put the function ParseandWarn(); above it.

Comment: System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
bij System.Int32.Parse(String s)

Comment: what was the input data you supplied?

Comment: You have to return `int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2;` and the (combined) bool parsing result from `ParseandWarn()` and use them wisely. It doesn't help if you use `TryParse` correctly and then `Parse` them again. `Parse` throws a FormatException if the string isn't an int - `TryParse` doesn't throw an exception, instead it returns a bool if the input could be parsed.

Comment: first two numbers, then a number and a letter. With this last one the messagebox show up, and then it freezes giving me the FormatException error

Comment: a number and letter.. what are you doing with the values `int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2` I don't see it being used, I am suspecting you are wanting to use those as placeholders for proper parsed ints, and compute the results?

Comment: How do i approach that in code? I'm just starting. I understand what you say but don't see how to code this ... sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the code that you are looking for.

I have used the `ref` as reference in the function `ParseandWarn`, that indicates that the parameters will be [modified by reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

```
public bool ParseandWarn(ref int Invoergetal1, ref int Invoergetal2){
    bool valid = false;
    if ((!int.TryParse(txtGetal1.Text, out Invoergetal1) || !int.TryParse(txtGetal2.Text, out Invoergetal2)) {
        MessageBox.Show("U dient een geheel getal in te voeren!", "Fout", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;   
}

private void btnSom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2;
    bool correctInput = ParseAndWarn(ref Invoergetal1, ref Invoergetal2);
    if(correctInput)
    {
       int BerekenSom = Invoergetal1 + Invoergetal2;
       txtResultaat.Text += "De som van " + txtGetal1.Text + " en " + txtGetal2.Text + " = " + BerekenSom + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

We pass in two `ints` into the function, gets a result of the `TryParse` method, if it fails, they will contain zero instead.

Now, the event handler will have the values, and by computing the sum of the two variables the result will be obtained.

**Edit** Extra checks for invalid inputs, or `null` is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help and thank you for the clear explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You run the ParseAndWarn() first. The following two lines should only run if the ParseAndWarn method found two correct numeric inputs. One way to do this is to let the ParseAndWarn method return a boolean to indicate if the Parse has succeeded

```
public bool ParseandWarn()
{
    int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtGetal1.Text, out Invoergetal1) || !int.TryParse(txtGetal2.Text, out Invoergetal2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("U dient een geheel getal in te voeren!", "Fout", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;   
}

private void btnSom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool correctInput = ParseAndWarn();
    if(correctInput)
    {
       int BerekenSom = int.Parse(txtGetal1.Text) + int.Parse(txtGetal2.Text);
       txtResultaat.Text += "De som van " + txtGetal1.Text + " en " + txtGetal2.Text + " = " + BerekenSom + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

You can also combine it all in your click event to avoid having to parse twice

```
private void btnSom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int Invoergetal1, Invoergetal2;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtGetal1.Text, out Invoergetal1) || !int.TryParse(txtGetal2.Text, out Invoergetal2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("U dient een geheel getal in te voeren!", "Fout", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
    else 
    {
       int BerekenSom = Invoergetal1 + Invoergetal2;
       txtResultaat.Text += "De som van " + Invoergetal1 + " en " + Invoergetal2 + " = " + BerekenSom + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't want to combine because i have multiple clicks (sum, product, ...).